# Why the boxplot made by ggplot is different to the one made by other software like Prsim?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I made a boxplot with ggplot using the following codes.

```
ggplot(data = df.08.long,
      aes(x = TMT_signals, y = as.numeric(TMT_Intensities), fill = `probe.Mod.or.not(Y/N)`)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ylim(0, 2.5e3) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=8),
        axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

Here is my data frame.

```
 structure(list(Scan.number = c(10017, 10017, 10017, 10017, 10017, 
    10017, 10017, 10017, 10017, 13240, 13240, 13240, 13240, 13240, 
    13240, 13240, 13240, 13240, 27592, 27592), Sequence = c("AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", 
    "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", 
    "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", 
    "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", 
    "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", 
    "AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR", "AAEQAHLWAELVFLYDKYEEYDNAIITMMNHPTDAWK", 
    "AAEQAHLWAELVFLYDKYEEYDNAIITMMNHPTDAWK"), Length = c(16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 37L, 37L), Missed.cleavages = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L
    ), Modified.sequence = c("_AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR_", 
    "_AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR_", 
    "_AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR_", 
    "_AAAYSAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAAY(XO44_TMT6)SAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAAY(XO44_TMT6)SAQVQPVDGATR_", 
    "_AAAY(XO44_TMT6)SAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAAY(XO44_TMT6)SAQVQPVDGATR_", 
    "_AAAY(XO44_TMT6)SAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAAY(XO44_TMT6)SAQVQPVDGATR_", 
    "_AAAY(XO44_TMT6)SAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAAY(XO44_TMT6)SAQVQPVDGATR_", 
    "_AAAY(XO44_TMT6)SAQVQPVDGATR_", "_AAEQAHLWAELVFLYDKYEEYDNAIITMMNHPTDAWK_", 
    "_AAEQAHLWAELVFLYDKYEEYDNAIITMMNHPTDAWK_"), probe_TMT6.Probabilities = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "AAAY(1)SAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAY(1)SAQVQPVDGATR", 
    "AAAY(1)SAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAY(1)SAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAY(1)SAQVQPVDGATR", 
    "AAAY(1)SAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAY(1)SAQVQPVDGATR", "AAAY(1)SAQVQPVDGATR", 
    "AAAY(1)SAQVQPVDGATR", "", ""), `Uniprot ID` = c("Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", 
    "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", 
    "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", 
    "Q9H7E9", "Q9H7E9", "Q00610", "Q00610"), `probe.Mod.or.not(Y/N)` = c("N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N"), `kinase.or.not(Y/N)` = c("N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), Gene.Names = c("C8orf33", "C8orf33", 
    "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "C8orf33", 
    "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "C8orf33", 
    "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "C8orf33", "CLTC", "CLTC"), 
        Charge = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), m.z = c(802.90499, 802.90499, 
        802.90499, 802.90499, 802.90499, 802.90499, 802.90499, 802.90499, 
        802.90499, 647.57262, 647.57262, 647.57262, 647.57262, 647.57262, 
        647.57262, 647.57262, 647.57262, 647.57262, 1107.5251, 1107.5251
        ), Score = c(86.313, 86.313, 86.313, 86.313, 86.313, 86.313, 
        86.313, 86.313, 86.313, 41.695, 41.695, 41.695, 41.695, 41.695, 
        41.695, 41.695, 41.695, 41.695, 28.532, 28.532), Retention.time = c(27.774, 
        27.774, 27.774, 27.774, 27.774, 27.774, 27.774, 27.774, 27.774, 
        35.978, 35.978, 35.978, 35.978, 35.978, 35.978, 35.978, 35.978, 
        35.978, 72.556, 72.556), Precursor.Intensity = c(460631.45703125, 
        460631.45703125, 460631.45703125, 460631.45703125, 460631.45703125, 
        460631.45703125, 460631.45703125, 460631.45703125, 460631.45703125, 
        472201.625, 472201.625, 472201.625, 472201.625, 472201.625, 
        472201.625, 472201.625, 472201.625, 472201.625, 388790.9296875, 
        388790.9296875), Localization.prob = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
        NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NaN, 
        NaN), probe_TMT6.site.IDs = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
        "", "", "308", "308", "308", "308", "308", "308", "308", 
        "308", "308", "", ""), TMT_signals = c("TMT126", "TMT127N", 
        "TMT128N", "TMT128C", "TMT129N", "TMT129C", "TMT130N", "TMT130C", 
        "TMT131", "TMT126", "TMT127N", "TMT128N", "TMT128C", "TMT129N", 
        "TMT129C", "TMT130N", "TMT130C", "TMT131", "TMT126", "TMT127N"
        ), TMT_Intensities = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1824.667, 
        3470.869, 1691.413, 2367.219, 1895.059, 1712.427, 1529.349, 
        1617.825, 1677.578, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the plot I got from ggplot.

[image]

Here is the boxplot I got from Prism.

[image]

It looks like the median values calculated by ggplot and by Prism are different. For example, the median value for `126 Y` in ggplot is ~ 1500, and the median value for `126 Y` in Prism is ~ 5000.

I checked my dataset, no NA values in these columns. The median values from my own calculation match those in Prism.

Does anyone know what was going on?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like the example data you shared produces that ggplot. For instance, your coded data only has one row for TMT_signals == TMT126 and prob.Mod.or.not = Y, which is not enough to make an interesting boxplot.

Comment: It would be helpful for potential answerers if you could reduce the data / code to just the parts relevant for your question. e.g. you probably only need the TMT_signals, TMT_Intensities, and probe.Mod.or.not(Y/N) columns to make the plot, and we don't need to see the theming parts of your code. That will make it quicker for you and us to hone in on the issue.

Comment: @JonSpring Is there a way to upload a .csv file? My data frame has > 19000 rows, and it takes forever to `dput` it.

Comment: I suspect the answer lies with your line `ylim(0, 2.5e3)`. If that fixes it, please read the help for `?ylim` for an explanation. You probably want to be using `coord_cartesian` to set the limits so that you don't distort your data summarization.

Comment: @JonSpring You are absolutely right! I didn't expect that `ylim` would remove the data. I thought that I just zoomed in on the figure. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in `ylim`, which, along with `scale_y_continuous(limits = ...)`, has a behavior that catches some users by surprise. As noted in the help at `?ylim`,

> This is a shortcut for supplying the limits argument to the individual
> scales. By default, any values outside the limits specified are
> replaced with NA. Be warned that this will remove data outside the
> limits and this can produce unintended results. For changing x or y
> axis limits without dropping data observations, see coord_cartesian().

This has a particularly confusing result during summary operations like what you'd have for `geom_boxplot()`, since it doesn't error out, it just produces a different result and a warning that you might miss or ignore.

For example, in the chart below, we'd expect a boxplot ranging from 0 to 100, but only get the zero value. That's because using `ylim` or `scale_y_continuous(limits = ...)` will both filter out the data outside the range before any summary calculations are performed.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1, y = c(0, 100))
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
   geom_boxplot() +
   ylim(c(0,90))
```

[image]

There's a warning but it's easy to miss or not realize its implications:

> Warning message: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values
> (stat_boxplot).

It's saying that one of the results was NA (after the step noted above) and is ignored from the statistics calculations.

To get the expected result, you should generally use `coord_cartesian(ylim =  ...)` to control the viewing window.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
   geom_boxplot() +
   coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,90))
```

[image]